# Prolog Recursive List Comparison

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I just started Prolog and for practice I'm trying to compare two lists and see if the first list is greater than the second list by one element. So far I got the base case to work, but for any list with more than one element it loops infinitely. Could anyone explain why this is happening? Any information is appreciated.

Code

```
one_longer([H],[]).
one_longer([H|T],[H2|T2]) :- one_longer([T],[T2]).
```

Answer (score 1):

The clause should be:

```
one_longer([H|T],[H2|T2]) :- one_longer(T,T2).
```

As `one_longer([T],[T2])` forms a new lists with only one element which results in the observed loop as when the rule is applied again results in continually asking `one_longer([[]],[[]])`  where as `one_longer(T,T2)` applies `one_longer` to the remainders of the two lists.